# What type of effect has been used in this site?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, effect

The website --> http://inspiredm.com is using an effect of hover in their post images . What kind of effect it is? It is a CSS3 or jquery effect and how to do similar effects ?

Comment: Have you tried viewing the site's source code?

Comment: @Brandon - my comment was meant for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's the opacity propriety on css, It doesn't work on ie8!

you may create this effect like this:

```
<a><img src="image.jpg" /></a>

a:hover {
background:#fff;
}

a:hover img {
opacity:0.7;
}
```

edit:

if you are referring to the post image load delay as you scroll the page, it's probably like lazy load plugin from jQuery:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Opacity isn't as standardized as it should be. Try { -moz-opacity:.50; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50; } in your CSS to make it work across most browsers.

Comment: And it becomes difficult to manage very, very quickly (thanks to inconsistent positioning between browsers). Sometimes you have to make compromises - unless your client considers fading images to be business critical! (and I've had those)

Comment: i mean, will it work with moz-opacity then? :) i tested with @RafaelMoni -'s solution . it works :) or to be sure should i use moz-opacity ?

Comment: actually there isn't a full-cross browser solution for this situation, moz-opacity should be used together with opacity to work on firefox 3.6 or older version, as well as webkit-opacity (not sure about sintax) to work with older version of chrome too, filter:alpha(opacity=60); should be used to work on ie8 and older version, that's a matter of time and critical business as Art Hanzel said!

Comment: -moz-opacity will work on earlier versions of Firefox and Mozilla-based browsers (FF2, seamonkey, songbird...). Opacity is (to the best of my knowledge) supported by every new browser (including IE9, but I can't vouch for <= 8), and the filter is for earlier versions of IE. I don't think the filter is animatable using jQuery - you'd have to use a 3rd party library for that.

Comment: Whoops, looks like Rafael beat me to it!

Comment: ok . have to do more research about the effect . though i will barely need support for IE older than 8 :-)

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be adding the class "imgHover" to the `<a>` tag that surrounds the image. This is done via JavaScript. Then in their stylesheet, they have `.imgHover img {opacity:0.7}`

So that site is using a combination of JS and CSS. It could also be done in pure css using the `:hover` pseudo-class (i.e. `img:hover {opacity:0.7}`), or by setting the opacity more directly with JavaScript. With jQuery, that would look something like:

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', 0.7);
}, function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);
});
```